# How to access name of fired event from within listener function?

Tags: javascript, events, listener, dom-events

I have enhanced a web-ui with a "class" that acts as a mediator between multiple possible events and multiple possible listeners instead of just one. The mediator object registers its own special function on the event as normal listener itself, which then is able to iterate over all possible listeners. If there already was a listener registered on the event before the mediator kicked in, it will be put into the mediator objects internal lists similar to other registeres listeners, causing it to be called on any registered event.

Because the mediator object takes in all previous listeners if there is any for the given event, it will call them all. This happens even if it's not there original event, which fires, but one of the other few events with are registered on the mediator object, too.

To prevent that, **I need to know the event which caused its listener(s) to be invoked**. E.g. when `window.onclick` fires, I want to know that it is `window.onclick`. What I have so far is the object from where the event is fired (through this-keyword), which is `window` in this particular case. How to I access this information and is it doable as cross-browser-solution?

To illustrate how that ominous mediator "class", also called `CallbackHandler`, is actually used:

```
// potential listener-functions
var callMeBaby = function () { console.log("Ya called me, Baby!"); };
var callMeWilhelm = function () { console.log("Ya called me, Wilhelm!"); };
var callMeMaybe = function () { console.log("Ya called me, maybe..."); };

// first listener assigned
window.onclick = callMeBaby;

// create 2 CallbackHandler-objects
// they use the same event window.onclick
// myButton.onclick is registered on anotherCH exlusively
// the previous listener window.onclick = callMeBaby will be included in windowOnClickCH
// windowOnClickCH.callback (the new listener) will replaced by anotherCH.callback as well
var windowOnClickCH = new Utilities.CallbackHandler();
windowOnClickCH.addSender(window, "onclick");
var anotherCH = new Utilities.CallbackHandler();
anotherCH.addSender(window, "onclick");
anotherCH.addSender(document.getElementById("myButton"), "onclick");

// register callback-function on the CallbackHandler-objects
windowOnClickCH.addReceiver(callMeWilhelm);
anotherCH.addReceiver(callMeMaybe);
```

This will result in more less these console-logs:

> Ya called me, Baby!
> Ya called me, Wilhelm!
> Ya called me, maybe...

Comment: Would the event target work? `var callMeMaybe = function ( event ) { console.log("Ya called me, maybe...");console.log(event.target); };` You might have to add the event object somewhere in the event mediator as well though, so that it gets passed to the function.

Comment: @Shilly The event.target won't do, unfortunately. It's still nice to know where the user clicked in in onclick-example, but it doesn't tell the mediator aka ``CallbackHandler`` anything it should care about.

Comment: Mh, the event-object itself has a type accessed through e.g. ``eventObj.type``. For the standard-onlick-events this becomes ``"click"``. Is this event-type unique for each dom-element? When there is an ``myObject.onclick`` with event-type ``click``, is it possible to have e.g. ``myObject.onClickfest`` with the same event-type?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the currentTarget property of the event object. "Event.currentTarget identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached." 
See this link for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Comment: When I print it to console, ``currentTarget`` is ``window`` in this example. I accessed the same object through ``this`` in the code of the listener-function. What I am really aiming for is ``window.onclick`` or something which let's me refer to it without a doubt.

Comment: Florian, when your listener function is called, it is passed an event object. One of the attributes of the event object is Event.type, which tells you specifically what event was fired. This is described in detail at this url: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-Event-type . Section 1.6.2 specifies the values which are returned from a mouse event, one of which is "click".